# POSTGRES stored procedure and SET session variable

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Does anyone know why this works this way? When I tried in other stored procedures and text is normally replaced with the value that is specified as stored procedure parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION setUserId(userId text)
returns void AS $$
    BEGIN 
    SET session "myapp.userId" = userId;
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
app=# select * from setUserId('myuserId');
 setuserid
-----------

(1 row)

app=# select current_setting('myapp.userId');
 current_setting
-----------------
 userid
(1 row)

app=#
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html),

```
SET session "myapp.userId" = userId
```

is equivalent to

```
SET session "myapp.userId" = 'userId'
```

so the input parameter name `userId` is considered as the new value for the run-time parameter instead of the input parameter value 'myuserId'.

If you want the run-time parameter to consider the value 'myuserId' of the input parameter `userId`, you need a dynamic statement :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION setUserId(userIdtext)
returns void AS $$
    BEGIN
    EXECUTE '
    SET session "myapp.userId" = ' || quote_nullable(userId) ;
    END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

demo in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6374d0b977621e8b3da5e95472faf4c9)

Comment: Alternatively use `set_config('myapp.userId', userid)`